# spring mvc uri with regular expression

Tags: spring-mvc, uri

having following pattern

```
public static final String URL_TOOLS_IMAGE_RESIZE_BOX_WITH_NAME
            = "/tools-box-{width:[0-9]+}-{height:[0-9]+}-{image:[0-9]{8}}/{imagename:.+}";
```

which leads to

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL_TOOLS_IMAGE_RESIZE_BOX_WITH_NAME,
            method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> resize_img_box(HttpServletRequest req,
            @PathVariable("image") String image,
            @PathVariable("imagename") String imagename,            
            @PathVariable("width") int width,
            @PathVariable("height") int height
    ) {
.......
```

it works just fine with

```
/tools-box-300-300-00000439/ime.jpg
```

and it wont with (leads to 404 )

```
/tools-box-300-300-00000439/ime.png

/tools-box-300-300-00000439/ime.gif
```

It seems `.png/.gif` means something to spring MVC. 
Could anyone provide detail information about this?

Answer (score 0):

it was

```
produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE
```

Comment: What about it? Please be more descriptive in your solution.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.